# Does the Cessna POH state the fuel consumption in Imperial or US Gallons?

Tags: fuel, units, poh

I'm planning a trip in a Cessna 182T and was calculating fuel requirements and started wondering. I have always assumed that fuel consumption is in US Gallons (or 3.785 litres) but I can't find a section in the Pilot's Operating Handbook (POH) that really confirms this. The fuel tank capacity is expressed in USG so I reckon it's close to assume that this implies that GPH is US gallons per hour.

There is a Imp. Gallon to Liter and Imp Gallon to US Gallon conversion table in the POH, when do we need Imp. Gallons?

Any comments, did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plane was certified with US Gallons. Use those for fuel consumption.

The conversion tables are there in case your FBO's fuel pump is calibrated in L or Imp Gal.

Comment: Okay... I came about 1 U.S. Inch from posting a long bewildered comment trying to understand what the airplane's fuel pump has to do with this, and then, I realized you are talking about the FBO's fuel sales pump.

Comment: @MortensenAviation, thank you for specifying that it was a _U.S. inch_, otherwise, we would have had to have another discussion about that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently flying cessna 152(ii) and I have my POH which is from the year of 1979. The fuel per consumption and other performance data are given in the performance section of the POH at section 5. The arrangement of data and other information are similar for all the POH. So you will get it in the section 5 probably. There are some tables which dictates information regarding cruise range, endurance, cruise performance. In the cruise performance chart you will get the consumption of fuel in accordance with temperature and RRP and if you have manifold pressure system you will have it on this chart hopefully. And for the calculation of fuel you will depend on the the calibration of the gauge you have in the cockpit. I think the on the chart of POH the fuel consumption is given in US Gallon.

Hopefully this will help you.